# Use Android specific code in MainPage.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

I am writing a cross-platform app. Now, assuming that the program is running on an Android device, I would like to call a class from the namespace ProjectName.Droid in my MainPage.xaml.cs, which is located in the namespace ProjectName. Is this possible and if not, is there another way to accomplish that.

Comment: see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MessasingCenter` in your `MainPage.xaml.cs` to send message to the code in `ProjectName.Droid`, providing that the code in .Droid `Subscribe` to that message. Details on implementation can be find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).

Second options is using dependency service as mentioned by @mshwf. This is where you write an interface in your Shared project, and call those methods normally.
Then you have to write the implementation of the interface in `.Droid` project.
A good example can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UsingDependencyService/)